# React- How to make states persists after page refresh?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router

I made a single page application using React.js with a login page and perfil page. All works well but recently **I noticed when refresh my page, all states are empty**. Please someone can say me how to fix that issue, I mean what library import and where add it

my **index.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './components/App.jsx';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';


ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));

serviceWorker.unregister();
```

this is my **App.jsx**

```
import React from 'react'; 
import '../App.css'; 
import AppRoutes from './AppRoutes'; 
import  { Provider }  from "react-redux";
import store from '../redux/store' 


store.dispatch(getTallerList())

const App = () => (
    <Provider store={store}>

        <AppRoutes />

    </Provider>   )

export default App;
```

and my **store.js**

```
import { applyMiddleware, combineReducers, createStore } from 'redux'
import { ADD_TO_CART, GET_COURSE_LIST, USUARIO_LOGIN } from './action'
import { composeWithDevTools } from 'redux-devtools-extension'
import { persistStore, persistReducer } from 'redux-persist'
import thunk from 'redux-thunk'



const initialCart = {
    cart:[]
}

const initialCourses ={
    courses:[]
}

const initialUser ={
    user:{}
}

const cartReducer = ( state = initialCart,action) => {


    if(action.type===ADD_TO_CART)
    {

        if(state.cart.find(c=>c===action.id)) 
        {
            return state
        }

        return{
            ...state,
            cart: state.cart.concat(action.id),            
        }

    }

    return state

}

const coursesReducer = (state=initialCourses, action) =>{
    console.log(action)
    if(action.type === GET_COURSE_LIST){
        return {
            ...state,
            courses: action.courses
        }
    }
    return state
}

const userReducer = (state=initialUser, action)=>{
    console.log(action)
    if(action.type === USER_LOGIN){
        return {
            ...state,
            user: action.user
        }
    }
    return state

}

export default createStore(combineReducers({cartReducer, coursesReducer, userReducer}), composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(thunk)))
```

Comment: Local Storage API, or cookies, or IndexDB.

Comment: Oh, you're using redux-persist.

Answer (score 0):

Try to store value in local storage and at the time of page load get value from local storage. If you have some more values you should use redux for data storage.

Answer (score 0):

Use this configuration as you are using **redux-persist**. This is my configuration, just change the **main app**, **reducers**, and **actions** according to your need.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import MyApp from './MyApp';
import {Provider} from 'react-redux';
import {applyMiddleware, createStore} from "redux";
import allReducers from './reducers/index';
import {persistReducer, persistStore} from 'redux-persist';
import {PersistGate} from 'redux-persist/integration/react';
import storage from 'redux-persist/lib/storage';
import thunk from "redux-thunk";

const persistConfig = {
    key: 'root',
    storage,
};

const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, allReducers);

let store = createStore(persistedReducer, applyMiddleware(thunk));
let persistor = persistStore(store);

ReactDOM.render(<Provider store={store}>
    <PersistGate loading={null} persistor={persistor}>
        <MyApp/>
    </PersistGate>
</Provider>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

**Updated :** you can do like this

```js
import {combineReducers} from "redux";
import Users from './load-user';



const allReducers = combineReducers({
    users: Users,
})

export default allReducers
```

Comment: When i import 'allReducers ' i got a problem. All my reducers is in 'store.js' (look up my question) so i dont know how import all my reducers like you did it

Comment: i did but when the page is rendered the message is 'TypeError: baseReducer is not a function' I dont know how fix it

Comment: Can you create a codesandbox and give the link. What you have done so far

Answer (score 0):

It's not an issue, it's the way it works. When you refresh the entire app builds once again from the scratch.

But to persist the store upon refresh you can use these `redux` middlewares -

1. [redux-persist](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-persist) or
2. [redux-storage](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-storage)